# Intuition about column versus row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Typically, we write a column vector $\vec{x}$ of $n$ elements as $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, we often think of $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ as a statement that $\vec{x}$ lives in three dimensional space.

Then we can define a row vector $\vec{y}$ such that $\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{1,n}$.  Then what does the statement $\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ mean geometrically, if it even has a geometric meaning?

An equivalent question: what is the intuitive meaning of transposing a vector that lives in a three-dimensional vector space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By itself $\Bbb{R}^n$ doesn't actually carry any information about being composed of column or row vectors. I think that the convention of considering it composed of column vectors is simply due to the usual definition of matrix product, which then gives a natural action of a matrix on $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Anyway, you can think of transposition as the canonical map from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to its [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space): in other words, you can think of $\vec{y}$ as a linear map from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}$ given by
$$
\langle \vec{y}^T, \vec{x} \rangle = \vec{y}\vec{x} = y_1 x_1 + \dotsc + y_n x_n.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Row vectors are usually coordinates of vectors in the *dual space* of $\mathbf R^n$, i.e. the row vector $(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ correspond to the *linear form* on $\mathbf R^n$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf R^n&\longrightarrow \mathbf R\\
(x_1,\dots,x_n)&\longmapsto a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n
\end{align*}